# Error C++ invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with this code. I don't know why it's wrong. I have no idea how to fix it.
I started learning C++ not long time ago, so sorry if the question is stupid.
This is a university exercise to special mathematics, and we have a teacher who didn't explain anything.

P.S. Visual Studio Code, compiler MinGW

Thanks ~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXfab.png)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int **matriceAdiacenta;
int matriceAdiacentaLungime = 0;
int **matriceIncidenta;
int matriceIncidentaLungime = 0,
matriceIncidentaArcs = 0;
int **ListAdiacentaiacenta;
int ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime = 0;
int meniu, tipcitireMeniu;
int **Virfulmatrice;
int virfmatrice=0;
fstream citireadinFisier;

void displayMtrAdiacenta()
{
system("cls");
if (matriceAdiacentaLungime < 1)
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice adiacenta" << endl;
else
{
int i, j;
cout << "Matricea de adiacenta:" << endl;
for (i = 1; i <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
cout << matriceAdiacenta[i][j] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
}
cout << endl
<< "Tastati oricare buton pentru revenirea la meniu";
getch();
}
void displayMatriceaIncidenta()
{
system("cls");
if (matriceIncidentaLungime < 1)
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice de incidenta" << endl;
else
{
int i, j;
cout << "Matricea de incidenta:" << endl;
for (i = 1; i <= matriceIncidentaArcs; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= matriceIncidentaLungime; j++)
cout << matriceIncidenta[i][j] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
}
cout << endl
<< "Tastati oricare buton pentru revenirea la meniu";
getch();
}
void displayListAdiacentaiacenta()
{
system("cls");
if (ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime < 1)
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o lista de adiacenta" << endl;
else
{
cout << "Lista de adiacenta:" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
cout << i + 1 << " - ";
j = 0;
while (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] != 0)
{
cout << ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] << " ";
j++;
}
cout << "0" << endl;
}
cout << endl << "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
}
void StergereArc(){
int i,x,y,j,m;
virfmatrice=0;
matriceIncidentaArcs=0;
return;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
matriceIncidentaArcs[x][y]=matriceIncidentaArcs[x+1][y+1];
virfmatrice[y][j]=virfmatrice[y+1][j+1];
}
x=x-1;
y=y-1;
i=i-1;
j=j-1;
}
void StergereVirf(){
int i,j,p,n;
matriceIncidentaArcs=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
matriceIncidentaArcs[j][p]=0;
matriceIncidentaArcs[i][p]=0;
matriceIncidentaArcs[p][j]=0;
}
}
}
void insertMatriceAdiacenta(int tip)
{
int i = 0,
j = 0;
if (tip == 1)
{
citireadinFisier.open("matrAd.txt", ios::in);
citireadinFisier >> matriceAdiacentaLungime;
matriceAdiacenta = new int *[matriceAdiacentaLungime + 1];
for (i = 1; i <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; i++)
{
matriceAdiacenta[i] = new int[matriceAdiacentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
{
citireadinFisier >> matriceAdiacenta[i][j];
}
}
citireadinFisier.close();
displayMtrAdiacenta();
}
else
{
cout<<"Lungimea: ";
cin >> matriceAdiacentaLungime;
matriceAdiacenta = new int *[matriceAdiacentaLungime + 1];
for (i = 1; i <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; i++)
{
matriceAdiacenta[i] = new int[matriceAdiacentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
{
cin >> matriceAdiacenta[i][j];
}
}
displayMtrAdiacenta();
}
}
void insertMatriceIncidenta(int tip)
{
int i = 0,
j = 0;
if (tip == 1)
{
citireadinFisier.open("matrInc.txt", ios::in);
citireadinFisier >> matriceIncidentaLungime >> matriceIncidentaArcs;
matriceIncidenta = new int *[matriceIncidentaArcs];
for (i = 1; i <= matriceIncidentaArcs; i++)
{
matriceIncidenta[i] = new int[matriceIncidentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= matriceIncidentaLungime; j++)
citireadinFisier >> matriceIncidenta[i][j];
}
citireadinFisier.close();
displayMatriceaIncidenta();
}
else
{
cout << endl<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
}
void insertListAdiacenta(int tip)
{
int i = 0,
j = 0;
if (tip == 1)
{
citireadinFisier.open("LstInc.txt", ios::in);
citireadinFisier >> ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime;
ListAdiacentaiacenta = new int *[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
while (!citireadinFisier.eof())
{
ListAdiacentaiacenta[i] = new int[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
j = 0;
do
{
citireadinFisier >> ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j];
j++;
}
while (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j - 1] != 0);
i++;
}
citireadinFisier.close();
displayListAdiacentaiacenta();
}
else
{
cout << "Lungimea: ";
cin >> ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime;
ListAdiacentaiacenta = new int *[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
for (i = 0; i < ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
ListAdiacentaiacenta[i] = new int[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
j = 0;
cout << i << " - ";
do
{
cin >> ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j];
if (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime)
j++;
} while (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] != 0);
}
citireadinFisier.close();
}
}
void matriceAdiacenta_ListAdiacenta()
{
system("cls");
if (matriceAdiacentaLungime == 0)
{
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice adiacenta" << endl;
}
else
{
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; i++)
{
cout << i << " - ";
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
{
if (matriceAdiacenta[i][j] == 1)
{
cout << j << " ";
}
}
cout << "0" << endl;
}
}
cout << endl<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
void matriceAdiacenta_MatriceIncident()
{
system("cls");
if (matriceAdiacentaLungime == 0)
{
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice adiacenta" << endl;
}
else
{
int arcs = 0, i, j, currArc = 1, **matr;
for (i = 1; i <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; i++)
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
if (matriceAdiacenta[i][j] == 1)
arcs++;
matr = new int *[arcs];
for (i = 1; i <= arcs; i++)
{
matr[i] = new int[matriceAdiacentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
matr[i][j] = 0;
}
for (i = 1; i <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; i++)
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
if (matriceAdiacenta[i][j] == 1)
{
matr[currArc][i] = -1;
matr[currArc][j] = 1;
currArc++;
}
for (i = 1; i <= arcs; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= matriceAdiacentaLungime; j++)
cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
}
cout << endl
<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
void matriceIncidenta_matriceAdiacenta()
{
system("cls");
if (matriceIncidentaLungime == 0)
{
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice de incidenta" << endl;
}
else
{
int **matr, matr_out, matr_in, i, j;
matr = new int *[matriceIncidentaLungime];
for (i = 1; i <= matriceIncidentaLungime; i++)
{
matr[i] = new int[matriceIncidentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= matriceIncidentaLungime; j++)
matr[i][j] = 0;
}
for (i = 1; i <= matriceIncidentaArcs; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= matriceIncidentaLungime; j++)
if (matriceIncidenta[i][j] == -1)
matr_out = j;
else if (matriceIncidenta[i][j] == 1)
matr_in = j;
matr[matr_out][matr_in] = 1;
}
//afisare
for (i = 1; i <= matriceIncidentaLungime; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= matriceIncidentaLungime; j++)
cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
}
cout << endl<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
void matriceIncidenta_ListAdiacenta()
{
system("cls");
if (matriceIncidentaLungime == 0)
{
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice de incidenta" << endl;
}
else
{
int i, j, k;
for (j = 1; j <= matriceIncidentaLungime; j++)
{
cout << j << " - ";
for (i = 1; i <= matriceIncidentaArcs; i++)
if (matriceIncidenta[i][j] == -1)
for (k = 1; k <= matriceIncidentaLungime; k++)
if (matriceIncidenta[i][k] == 1)
{
cout << k << " ";
break;
}
cout << "0" << endl;
}
}
cout << endl<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
void ListAdiacenta_matriceIncidenta()
{
system("cls");
if (ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime == 0)
{
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o matrice adiacenta" << endl;
}
else
{
int k = 0, i, j, **matr;
for (i = 0; i < ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
j = 0;
while (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] != 0)
{
k++;
j++;
};
}
matr = new int *[k];
for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
{
matr[i] = new int[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; j++)
{
matr[i][j] = 0;
}
}
k = 1;
for (i = 0; i < ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
j = 0;
while (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] != 0)
{
matr[k][i + 1] = -1;
matr[k][ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j]] = 1;
k++;
j++;
};
}
for (i = 1; i <= k - 1; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; j++)
cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
}
cout << endl<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
void ListAdiacenta_matriceAdiacenta()
{
system("cls");
if (ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime == 0)
{
cout << "Va rugam sa introduceti o lista de adiacenta" << endl;
}
else
{
int **matr, i, j;
matr = new int *[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
for (i = 1; i <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
matr[i] = new int[ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime];
for (j = 1; j <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; j++)
matr[i][j] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
j = 0;
while (ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j] != 0)
{
matr[i + 1][ListAdiacentaiacenta[i][j]] = 1;
j++;
};
}
for (i = 1; i <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= ListAdiacentaiacentaLungime; j++)
cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
}
cout << endl<< "Apasa orice pentru a merge la meniul principal";
getch();
}
int main()
{
bool stop = false;
while (!stop)
{
cout << "1 - Introduceti un graf" << endl;
cout << "2 - Afisarea grafului" << endl;
cout << "3 - Afisati alt tip prin schimbarea celui existent" << endl;
cout << "4 - Stergere" << endl;
cout << "5 - Iesire" << endl;
cin >> meniu;
if (meniu == 1)
{
system("cls");
cout << "1 - Matrice de adiacenta" << endl;
cout << "2 - Matrice de incidenta" << endl;
cout << "3 - Lista de adiacenta" << endl;
cin >> meniu;
system("cls");
cout << "1 - Din fisier" << endl;
cout << "2 - De la tastatura" << endl;
cin >> tipcitireMeniu;
if (meniu == 1)
insertMatriceAdiacenta(tipcitireMeniu);
else if (meniu == 2)
insertMatriceIncidenta(tipcitireMeniu);
else if (meniu == 3)
insertListAdiacenta(tipcitireMeniu);
system("cls");
}
else if (meniu == 2)
{
system("cls");
cout << "1 - Matrice de adiacenta" << endl;
cout << "2 - Matrice de incidenta" << endl;
cout << "3 - Lista de adiacenta" << endl;
cout << "next ";
cin >> meniu;
if (meniu == 1)
displayMtrAdiacenta();
if (meniu == 2)
displayMatriceaIncidenta();
if (meniu == 3)
displayListAdiacentaiacenta();
system("cls");
}
else if (meniu == 3)
{
system("cls");
cout << "1 - Matrice Adiacenta -> Lista Adiacenta" << endl;
cout << "2 - Matrice Adiacenta -> Matrice Incidenta" << endl;
cout << "3 - Matrice Incidenta -> Matrice Adiacenta" << endl;
cout << "4 - Matrice Incidenta -> Lista Adiacenta" << endl;
cout << "5 - Lista Adiacenta -> Matrice Incidenta" << endl;
cout << "6 - Lista Adiacenta -> Matrice Adiacenta" << endl;
cin >> meniu;
switch (meniu)
{
case 1:
matriceAdiacenta_ListAdiacenta();
break;
case 2:
matriceAdiacenta_MatriceIncident();
break;
case 3:
matriceIncidenta_matriceAdiacenta();
break;
case 4:
matriceIncidenta_ListAdiacenta();
break;
case 5:
ListAdiacenta_matriceIncidenta();
break;
case 6:
ListAdiacenta_matriceAdiacenta();
break;
default:
break;
}
system("cls");
}
else if (meniu == 4)
{
cout << "1 - Stergerea arcului" << endl;
cout << "2 - Stergerea virfului" << endl;
cin >> meniu;
switch (meniu)
{
case 1:
StergereArc();
break;
case 2:
StergereVirf();
break;
default:
break;
}
system("cls");}
else
{
stop = true;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minimize your example. See [mcve]

Comment: it is a minimize example .D

Comment: Did you read the link?  You are claiming that there is not one line you could remove from that wall of code and get the same error?  It is not minimal.

Comment: Delete `cout << endl
<< "Tastati oricare buton pentru revenirea la meniu";
getch();` and the error still happens.  Thus your example is not minimal.  So, go minimize it.  Every line, see if deleting it keeps the error intact. When every statement, when deleted, changes the error, your example will be more minimal.  Post that code.

Comment: Your code is very confusing that you don't indent at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems, but the one you ask about is this:

Among the declarations at the top, you have:

```
int matriceIncidentaLungime = 0,
matriceIncidentaArcs = 0;
```

This declares two different ints, and initializes both to zero. Using comma to declare multiple variables on one line is legal, but something you should stop doing right away - it is a real code smell. Instead, you should write:

```
int matriceIncidentaLungime = 0;
int matriceIncidentaArcs = 0;
```

But the real bug, is that you are using matriceIncidentaArcs as it was declared as a 2-dimensional arrays, and not as a plain int:

```
matriceIncidentaArcs[x][y]=matriceIncidentaArcs[x+1][y+1];
```

For this to work, matriceIncidentaArcs needs to be a 2d array (preferable a vector<vector>, not an int[][].

But this is just one of the many problems in your code.

The pointers and double pointers you declare, screams of bugs that will explode your code when you get as far as running it. Don't use pointers until you know what you're doing. Instead, start learing std::vector or std::array

By doing that, you will be able to use ranged-based for loops instead of the raw for-loops you are mis-using too.